# Time direction in the BH parallel exterior region

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, relativity, causality, wormholes

In the III region of the [maximally extended Schwarzschild solution](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1c/Kruskal_diagram_of_Schwarzschild_chart.svg), described in the Kruskal coordinates , Sch. time runs in the reversed direction as compared to the I - event horizon III-II of the photon from III is at the past infinity, while the III-IV is at the future infinity. This is refered to as a [``mirror wormhole''](http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/bh/schwm.html)

I have seen that this is sometimes interpreted as if the both I and III have the same time direction? How so?

Does this means that the future singularity of the photon emitted in I is the past singularity of the photon emitted in III? Vice versa, is the past singularity of the photon from I future singularity of the photon in III. In other words, do Black Hole and White Hole exchange position between I and III?

Answer (score 0):

> In the III region of the maximally extended Schwarzschild solution, described in the Kruskal coordinates , Sch. time runs in the reversed direction as compared to the I - event horizon III-II of the photon from III is at the past infinity, while the III-IV is at the future infinity.

Not true. This is an obscure attempted reinterpretation of this spacetime, and it has unacceptable physical properties, for the reasons described in your link.

> This is refered to as a ``mirror wormhole''

He's using this term only to describe the nonstandard attempted interpretation.

> Does this means that the future singularity of the photon emitted in I is the past singularity of the photon emitted in III?

In this interpretation, the two singularities are considered to be the same, and regions I and III are considered to be the same.